# Build specific modules OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'd like to ask how can I specify OpenCV modules to build by cmake ex. I'd like to build only core, highgui and improc.

Thank you for your responses because I googled it and I can't find it. :(

Mari

Comment: I am in the same boat. But, let me specify my need: minimal CORE. what is the minimal?

Comment: Core is a package in opencv which stores stuff like cv::MAT which is used by every other modules. Also, for anyone here having trouble with cmake stuff, use https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html . THis will teach you most tricks for what dependencies, modules are in opencv as well as cmake tricks to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can toggle each module by specifying it to cmake:

```
-DBUILD_opencv_xxxx=OFF # where xxxx is the module in question, and ON or OFF is your requested state
```

with cmake

Comment: Any idea of there is a way to only build a few modules and still build the python module?

Comment: What are the names of the modules?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You say how to turn off building a module, but not how to turn off building ALL modules except the ones you specify.

Comment: @James The modules are the folders in the `modules` folder. `cmake-gui` is quite handy as well, as it shows a list where you can select all the modules you want.

Comment: @ArthurTacca For OpenCV 3.3.1 and older there is unfortunately no way around manually disabling every single module.

Answer (score 35):

In the CMakeCache.txt file there is an option BUILD_LIST. You can edit that file directly or specify it on the command line

**CMakeCache.txt, relevant line**

`//Build only listed modules (comma-separated, e.g. 'videoio,dnn,ts')
BUILD_LIST:STRING=`

**Command line**

`cmake -DBUILD_LIST=core,highgui,improc ..`

Comment: Note that this only works with OpenCV 3.4 or higher (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/5b17410f7cd89d3f6b9a7def79e8ad1a670daf21)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Cmake GUI to see what you are building 
just point Cmake GUI to the directory of opencv source code.
then you choose the compiler version you would like to compile with.
[image]

Once generation is done. you have a very nice UI representation of what you would like to build.

[image]