# Do I have to to rebuild opencv over again to add opencv_contrib?

Tags: linux, opencv, makefile, cmake

Is it possible to build opencv_contrib without building them together ( I mean with the official version)? , because I've already built the official one (Version 3), and I'm wondering if I'm going to affect the installed one if I install the contrib version alone separately in the location of the installed one.

Note: I'm on linux

Comment: I also had the same issue, and ended up rebuilding whole library again. But maybe this answer may help (not the accepted answer, other one):  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594003/build-specific-modules-opencv

Comment: That question is about installing 3 modules from the official version not the contrib one, I'm coming to the conclusion that you can't build it alone because it does't have a makefile in the main contrib folder.
thank you

Comment: I was trying to say maybe you could build less modules from official version while building library.

Comment: From that answer it seems that you can do that.