# Can I build OpenCV for embedded platform with ONLY the required headers

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, cross-platform

I am trying to build Opencv for an `arm` application where I need to use minimum space.

My application program is a very simple LBP cascade based image detector.
It includes the following **headers**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
```

Thus I link the following **libraries**

```
-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect
-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

For this I started trying to build opencv with [CrossCompilation Method](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html). My script is given here

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/opencv-home/build_arm/install \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-hisiv400-linux-gcc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-hisiv400-linux-g++ \
-DCMAKE_LINKER=arm-hisiv400-linux-g++ \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/path/to/opencv_contrib-home/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/opencv-home/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake /path/to/opencv-home
```

For this I run into plethora of errors like `error: ‘exception_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’`

**---MY QUESTION---**
Can I specifically build the OPENCV for arm platform for the headers & libraries I used? if yes, how?

Comment: From what I know, the way you build for ARM is by using the respective toolchain, in your case, the ARM-gcc toolchain. Did you see any errors while building opencv? If not, check your project settings, the target should be set to ARM, not x86 or x64.

Comment: @Roy2511 **`errors while building opencv`** Yes I am unable to build opencv for arm. As I said, i am getting `error: ‘exception_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’` like errors. Thus I am thinking only to build the required packages (if possible) that way I can reduce the number of errors... right?

Comment: "Can I specifically build the OPENCV for arm platform for the headers & libraries I used?" - Have you checked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594003/build-specific-modules-opencv? It describes how to select OpenCV modules to be built.