# How to get list of opencv modules?

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake

I just want to use `imread` function from opencv.

How to get list of opencv modules and disable them during opencv build from sources process?

Comment: Do you mean making them ```ON-OFF``` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594003/build-specific-modules-opencv/50616437)

Comment: Seems this can be an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50616437/1179925

But how list all module names?

Comment: The list of modules which are listed [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html) are written in the folder ```opencv/modules/CMakeLists.txt```

Comment: Can we assume that modules are just folders under https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules ?

Some more info:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9893

Answer (score 0):

In the official OpenCV website you can find all the modules and their functionality [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/index.html).

As of OpenCV 4.6 the main modules are:

- core. Core functionality
- imgproc. Image Processing
- imgcodecs. Image file reading and writing
- videoio. Video I/O
- highgui. High-level GUI
- video. Video Analysis
- calib3d. Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction
- features2d. 2D Features Framework
- objdetect. Object Detection
- dnn. Deep Neural Network module
- ml. Machine Learning
- flann. Clustering and Search in Multi-Dimensional Spaces
- photo. Computational Photography
- stitching. Images stitching
- gapi. Graph API