# OpenCVSharp4 Huge DLLs size

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, clickonce

I am trying to user opencvsharp4 package for webcam. I have a click once application but is 18 MB in size in total.

But I can see some of the nativedlls it comes up with OpenCvSharpExtern.dll is 40 MB+, opencv_videoio_ffmpeg480.dll is 22 MB+.

I wonder that will make my application size to 100 MB +.

Is there a way to reduce these dll size in KBs otherwise it is a big negative to use this package -:(

Try to reduce the native dll size or a way to lazy load them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to reduce these dll size

The short answer is no: the project itself (https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) is a wrapper around ALL the existing C++ code and bundles it one nuget package.

The longer answer is, **theoretically yes**. The original C++ OpenCV project is divided into [separate modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/modules), so it is theoretically possible to build only the modules you need or use and then just use that custom-built version of the library. Here's another SO answer that covers selectively building the C++ project this by changing the CMAKE settings:  [Build specific modules OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594003/build-specific-modules-opencv)

However if you go down this route, you have to generate your own C# wrapping PInvoke code yourself.

Comment: Can you guide me exactly which modules need to be build to use the camera?

Comment: Okay, I choosed not to use opencvsharp but decided on using windows native libraries to capture and access webcam